# Nic Edit : Bullet point in not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nicedit

I have used ' Nic Edit ' in my rails project .

Bullet point ( ol and ul ) is not working .

I have checked nicEDIT.js.erb

it is there in button list .

Bold , Italic and others are working except this 'ol' and 'ul' .

Comment: I have got the solution . That was a CSS problem . These two classes fixed the problem 


.nicEdit-main ol{
`list-style:inside;`    
`list-style-type: decimal;`   
}

.nicEdit-main ul{
`list-style: inside;`    
`list-style-type: circle;`    
}

Comment: perhaps my answer helped?  Feel free to upvote it as useful if it did :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have got the solution . That was a CSS problem . These two classes fixed the problem

```
.nicEdit-main ol{ list-style:inside; list-style-type: decimal; }
.nicEdit-main ul{ list-style: inside; list-style-type: circle; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you have a css style that is changing these.

Check your css styles for any changes to ul/ol.

Comment: Thanks Michael Durrant . Yea that was a CSS problem and I have fixed that .